# type SForceService is not defined vb.net Salesforce wsdl

Tags: api, soap-api

I am attempting to use the Saleforce WSDL to integrate a VB.net website into my company's Salesforce.com ORG.

I have followed all instructions at both https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET as well as StackExchange (referring to editing the WSDL to correct the unbounded ListViewRecord element.

Unfortunately, I am still unable to call the SForceService class or any other SF API classes (i.e. LoginResult)

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   BC30002 Type 'SforceService' is not defined.    EquipmentTracker    C:...\EquipmentTracker\EquipmentTracker\SFLogon.vbhtml 10  Active

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What did you name the Web reference when you imported the WSDL?

Comment: @DanielBallinger `SFDC`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all familiar with VB.NET. You will likely want the `SforceServiceService` class that gets generated within the SFDC namespace to access the web service.

[image]